# Rotate camera around point of view

Tags: unity, camera, rotate

I'm trying to rotate the camera around the view point of the camera. So when the user looks at a build the camera rotate around that building. But the camera does not need to have the building to rotate around. So therefore I want a camera that can rotate around his own point of view. So that the camera behave everywhere the same in the game.

How can I achieve this in Unity 5.6?

Answer (score -1):

The answer you're looking for is Arcball rotation, similar to the rotation button in the scene view.

There's a pretty good answer (though related to OpenGL and not Unity) here:

[How can I orbit a camera about it's target point?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20758/how-can-i-orbit-a-camera-about-its-target-point)

A cursory search for Arcball rotation with Unity doesn't net any specific code examples, that I could find, though the accepted answer in the above link is a great jumping off point.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a Transform variable and set it to the building's center point. Then rotate the camera around it depending on the mouse input.

Comment: Except the OP clearly stated that there isn't always a building to rotate around, which I'm extrapolating to mean the camera needs to rotate around a point in space rather than a specific object, hence my answer regarding Arcball rotation (which is typically for rotating an object, but can also be used to rotate the camera around a set point in space).

Comment: Err, maybe not a "set point" in space, but around it's currently targeted view.