# Creating a custom camera in Godot

Tags: camera, rotation, godot

Allow me to start with what I'm trying to achieve - there might be an easier way to do this and I'm just overcomplicating things.

I'm trying to implement a camera, that will be able to rotate around a single pivot point. The point doesn't have to move (although accounting for it might be useful for the future). I found [this answer](https://godotengine.org/qa/79848/how-to-do-runescape-camera-movements-w-arrow-keys?show=79895#a79895) on Godot's Q&A that suggest a simple solution - nest the camera under a single `Spatial` node. Just by doing that and toying around with node properties in editor, I'm able to move the camera just in the way I wanted by applying simple transformations (on my end, the engine certainly has to calculate everything).

This would have been it, except for this simple issue. Let's say I want this camera to be reusable - I pack it into a `PivotedCamera` scene and instantiate it in my main game scene. Now whenever I want to access the camera's methods (`project_ray_origin()`, etc.), I have to go one layer deeper into the scene tree. Swapping a `Camera` for `PivotedCamera` now requires a change to the code. What is the most sensible way to solve that?

My current idea is to simply implement [`Camera`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera.html)'s methods in the parent `Spatial` node which merely call the child's methods and return the values, but that feels clunky and prone to breaking changes when new methods are added to the `Camera` class. A scenario that I'd prefer would be somehow returning a reference to the `Camera` child in the `get_node("CameraPivot")` call, instead of a reference to the `Spatial` node. I do not (should not) need to access the `Spatial` node as all transforms are done in an attached script and react to input.

**P.S.:** [This answer here on Gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/20769/150154) goes deeper into solving the same issue, except in plain OpenGL, however, it feels a bit too "spartan" to be a good solution in Godot. Please do correct me if it is the best way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I want to say, I sympathize. I have gone down the path of making a custom variation of a Node by composition and turning it into a scene and then having to rely on reaching deep into the structure to use it. And I have also  implemented property delegates for ease of use.

The current Godot response is Editable Children. You can instance a scene with editable children, and this will allow you to overwrite the properties of the children on the editor.

*There have also been some proposals. For example: [Automate delegation of exported properties to internal nodes to improve GDScript abstractions](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/361).*

---

> but that feels clunky and prone to breaking changes when new methods are added to the Camera class.

I submit to you that the engine will not change behind your back.

If you are making a game, you decide if and when you upgrade to a new version of the engine, at which point you can update your class.

If you are making an addon or library, it is expected that you would release a new version if there are significant changes to the engine.

*And you might even have a tool generate the code for your custom class.*

*However, I understand this is not ideal.*

---

On the issue with what you want…

You could talk directly to `VisualServer` to create a low level camera (which is what the `Camera` node does behind the scenes). Or you could simply create the `Camera` node from code. But the node that does it would not be a `Camera`. So when you get it with `get_node`, what you get is not a `Camera`.

That leads you to either delegate the properties of a `Camera`… Or extend `Camera` except its `Transform` will not longer be the position of the camera, instead the position would be based on that `Transform` plus some other `Transform` that describe its motion around a point. That is, you want to break Liskov substitution principle.

The correct approach, is not to make a `Camera`, but a thing that has a `Camera`, and there is a perfectly reasonable to do that in engine: A `Spatial` with a `Camera`. And there is a perfectly reasonable way to reuse it: a scene. We are not going to change that.

So, we need a workaround `get_node` to get a `Camera`, and we need a solution to delegate the properties.

---

Before we go into that, I want to suggest an alternative approach. Consider that sometimes you might want to orbit something around something else… And have that first something not be a `Camera`. It is possible to create a custom `Node` that extends `Spatial`, that has the logic to orbit around something else (perhaps taking advantage of a `NodePath`). You can conceptualize it as a `Joint`, or you can conceptualize it a `RemoteTransform`.

In fact, it might be useful to have different controls for the `Camera` (e.g. first person, third person orbiting around the player, looking from a fixed position in a room, etc) and interpolate between them with an `InterpolatedCamera`. In fact, you don't necessarily need custom `Camera`s for those cases, you just need `Spatial`s to serve as targets for the `InterpolatedCamera`.

---

Not convinced? Ok...

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.

-- Attributed to Butler Lampson

So, we have `Camera`s, and we have `Camera`-like things. Let us call them `CameraHolder`. We are going to make a helper that gives you a `Camera` regardless if you give it a `Camera` or a `CameraHolder`. Easy:

```
class_name CameraGetter extends Object

static func from(node:Node) -> Camera:
    var camera_holder:CameraHolder = node as CameraHolder
    var camera:Camera

    if is_instance_valid(camera_holder)
        camera = camera_holder.get_camera()
    else:
        camera = node as Camera

    if is_instance_valid(camera)
        return camera

    return null
```

And now you can say `CameraGetter.from(get_node("CameraPivot"))` and it will give you a `Camera`.

We of course need to write the class `CameraHolder`. It must have a `get_camera` method. And we want to be able to use as if it were a `Camera`, in particular we want to appear to have all the properties of a `Camera`.

And that last part is tricky. This is the outline of what we will use:

```
tool class_name CameraHolder extends Spatial

func get_camera() -> Camera:
    return null

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return []

func _get(property: String):
    return null

func _set(property: String, value) -> bool:
    return false
```

First thing to notice is that there is a method `get_camera`, which in this case returns null. We will make everything else will refer to that `get_camera` method, so that a class that extends this one can simply override it.

Second, we are using `_get_property_list`. Godot will call `get_property_list` (which will call `_get_property_list` behind the scenes) to figure out what properties the `Node` exposes. In particular `_get_property_list` must return what *additional* properties the `Node` exposes. *With `_get_property_list` you can do what you would do with `export` and much more.*

The idea is to report all the properties of a `Camera`, and we can get one of those from `get_camera`, so we will use that to get its properties. We don't want to tell the editor to persist these properties, because we will delegate them to a `Camera` node that can be persisted instead. I will come back to that.

Then we have `_get` and `_set`, which will handle the case when we set properties that the `Node` does not have. However, you need to know that Godot will call them first, and only when they report that the property does not exist, then it will go to an actual property.

This is a problem, because we cannot rely on whether or not the `Camera` has a property, because our `Node` is also a `Spatial` and we don't want to delegate the its properties.

*In fact, one of the properties is the `script`, and I spent a lot of time figuring out why the script was disappearing. It was because I was delegating the `script` property to a `Camera` that didn't have a script.*

This problem is further complicated by the fact that calling `get` from `_get` will result in a stack overflow. *Similarly calling `get_property_list` from `_get_property_list` is a stack overflow.* And Godot will crash.

Thus, first we need to somehow sort out what properties do an `Spatial` have.

**Addendum**: Using [`ClassDB.class_get_property_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_classdb.html#class-classdb-method-class-get-property-list) is a better way to do this (so we don't have to create a node to ask it about its properties and we don't need to memoize the results). However, I'm keeping my old solution for reference.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
var _spatial_property_names:Array = []

func _get_spatial_property_names() -> Array:
    if _spatial_property_names.size() == 0:
        var spatial = Spatial.new()
        var spatial_properties = spatial.get_property_list()
        for property in spatial_properties:
            if property.type == TYPE_NIL:
                continue

            _spatial_property_names.append(property.name)

        spatial.free()
    
    return _spatial_property_names
```

That is, we are going to create a new `Spatial`, and ask it what properties does it have. We also skip `TYPE_NIL`, because these are used to communicate property categories to the editor. They are not real properties. And, of course, also memoize the result in an array for future reference. *We don't want to make a node every time we need this.*

---

Now, we can build our property list like this:

```
var _camera_properties:Array = []

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    var spatial_property_names = _get_spatial_property_names()
    if _camera_properties.size() == 0:
        var camera:Camera = get_camera()
        if is_instance_valid(camera):
            var properties = camera.get_property_list()
            for property in properties:
                if !spatial_property_names.has(property.name):
                    property.usage = property.usage & ~PROPERTY_USAGE_STORAGE 
                    _camera_properties.append(property)

    return _camera_properties
```

As you can see, if a property is in the list of properties that `Spatial` has, it is not an additional property. It would be a duplicate. And we don't report it.

For those that we report, we make sure they don't have the flag `PROPERTY_USAGE_STORAGE` set, so the editor will not persist them. *We, of course, want to let the editor persist the `Spatial` properties, which we skipped.*

And we are also memoizing this result.

---

Finally, these are `_get` and `_set`:

```
func _get(property: String):
    var spatial_property_names = _get_spatial_property_names()
    if spatial_property_names.has(property):
        return null

    var camera:Camera = get_camera()
    if is_instance_valid(camera):
        return camera.get(property)

    return null

func _set(property: String, value) -> bool:
    var spatial_property_names = _get_spatial_property_names()
    if spatial_property_names.has(property):
        return false

    var camera:Camera = get_camera()
    if is_instance_valid(camera) and property in camera:
        get_camera().set(property, value)
        return true

    return false
```

As you would expect, we rely on `_get_spatial_property_names` to know what property to avoid delegating to the `Camera`.

*Ah, and `get_camera` can keep returning null. It is ok. We are checking with `is_instance_valid` everywhere we use it.*

Now, we can extend that class to implement `CameraPivot`:

```
tool class_name CameraPivot extends CameraHolder

func get_camera() -> Camera:
    if is_inside_tree():
        return get_node_or_null("Camera") as Camera

    return null
```

Here I'm being extra careful because I know Godot will call this in `_get_property_list`. So I do not to call `get_node` which can result in an error, I call `get_node_or_null`. And I do not call `get_node_or_null` if the `Node` is not in the scene tree.

And this is my implementation for the orbit logic:

```
export(float) var orbit_distance:float setget set_orbit_distance
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_yaw:float setget set_orbit_yaw
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_pitch:float setget set_orbit_pitch
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_roll:float setget set_orbit_roll

func set_orbit_distance(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_distance = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_yaw(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_yaw = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_pitch(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_pitch = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_roll(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_roll = new_value
    update_transform()

func update_transform() -> void:
    var camera:Camera = get_camera()
    if !is_instance_valid(camera):
        return

    camera.transform = \
          Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.UP, deg2rad(orbit_yaw)) \
        * Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.RIGHT, deg2rad(orbit_pitch)) \
        * Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.FORWARD, deg2rad(orbit_roll)) \
        * Transform.IDENTITY.translated(Vector3.BACK * orbit_distance)
```

You don't have to do it this way, of course. You can extend `CameraHolder` and implement `get_camera` to get you the `Camera` from wherever you have it, and add whatever properties and methods make sense to you.

*The only thing missing is that the "Preview" toggle will not appear for out `CameraHolder` or our `CameraPivot`. I suppose this can addressed with a custom gizmo (which is a type of plugin). However, I haven't delved into that.*

---

### Addendum on subclassing `Camera`.

One of the problem I ran on while testing the above solution was that I was delegating some properties that I shouldn't. Which have led to the question: Can we intercept a property? And I don't mean to override it, much less remove it. The property must remain there, and still work, so it does not break any functionality.

As you know, if we do this:

```
extends Camera

var transform:Transform
```

We get an error. That does not work.

But… We can use `_get` and `_set`!

The first part to figure out was what to intercept. So I set a `_get` and `_set` that would print whatever property is being access. And I found a couple things:

- Moving the node from the spatial gizmo avoid `_get` and `_set` entirely. Will deal with that later.
- Moving the node from the inspector panel will interact with "scale", "translation" and "rotation_degrees"

So we will intercept those, and of course "transform" too. That is something like this:

```
tool extends Camera

var _base_transform:Transform

func _get(property: String):
    match property:
        "transform":
            return self._base_transform
        "scale":
            return self._base_transform.basis.get_scale()
        "translation":
            return self._base_transform.origin
        "rotation_degrees":
            return self._base_transform.basis.get_euler() * 180/PI
        _:
            return null

func _set(property: String, value) -> bool:
    match property:
        "transform":
            self._base_transform = value
            return true
        "scale":
            var quat = self._base_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
            self._base_transform.basis = Basis(quat).scaled(value)
            return true
        "translation":
            self._base_transform.origin = value
            return true
        "rotation_degrees":
            var scale = self._base_transform.basis.get_scale()
            self._base_transform.basis = Basis(Quat(value * PI/180)).scaled(scale)
            return true
        _:
            return false
```

*Those `self` will become relevant soon.*

With this code, when you modify the transform from the inspector panel, you are actually editing this new `_base_transform` variable.

Now, we want to reintroduce our orbit properties. These look the same:

```
export(float) var orbit_distance:float setget set_orbit_distance
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_yaw:float setget set_orbit_yaw
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_pitch:float setget set_orbit_pitch
export(float, -180, 180) var orbit_roll:float setget set_orbit_roll

func set_orbit_distance(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_distance = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_yaw(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_yaw = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_pitch(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_pitch = new_value
    update_transform()

func set_orbit_roll(new_value:float) -> void:
    orbit_roll = new_value
    update_transform()
```

But we will change `update_transform` to this:

```
func get_relative_transform() -> Transform:
    return Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.UP, deg2rad(orbit_yaw)) \
    * Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.RIGHT, deg2rad(orbit_pitch)) \
    * Transform.IDENTITY.rotated(Vector3.FORWARD, deg2rad(orbit_roll)) \
    * Transform.IDENTITY.translated(Vector3.BACK * orbit_distance)

func update_transform() -> void:
    transform = _base_transform * get_relative_transform()
```

That is, I extracted `get_relative_transform` from `update_transform`. *And also, I'm not dealing with a child `Camera`, since the `Camera` is the `Node` we are working on.*

Why?

Well, as I said, when we move the `Node` using the spatial gizmo, that avoids `_get` and `_set`. We need changes to `_base_transform` to become changes to `transform` and changes to `transform` to become changes to `_base_transform`. We accomplish this by giving a getter and a setter to `_base_transform`:

```
var _base_transform:Transform setget set_base_transform, get_base_transform

func set_base_transform(new_value:Transform) -> void:
    _base_transform = new_value
    update_transform()

func get_base_transform() -> Transform:
    _base_transform = transform * get_relative_transform().affine_inverse()
    return _base_transform
```

And there we are using `get_relative_transform()` which is why we extracted it from `update_transform`.

Also, the reason why I wrote access to `_base_transform` with `self` is to make sure it called the getter and setter.

There is just one more thing to do: make sure `_base_transform` gets persisted. We could do it by using `export`. However, to not have it appear in the inspector panel, we use `_get_property_list`, like this:

```
func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    var properties = []
    properties.append({
        name = "_base_transform",
        type = TYPE_TRANSFORM,
        usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_STORAGE
    })
    return properties
```

*I believe this approach would benefit from yet another spatial gizmo, one that eases setting the point around the camera orbits. And again, I don't know enough about gizmos to about implementing that. The approach I would follow to use this node without such gizmo is to set the orbit properties at zero, position the camera at the point it will orbit around, and then edit the orbit properties to what you want.*

Comment: At times like these, I wish I could upvote an answer twice...